# sorting lists with lowercase, capitals, and numbers

Tags: bash, sorting

I would like to clean-up & sort the returned output of a bash command.

Currently the output is pretty disorganized:

```
00000000-0000-0000-A000-4A414D460003
C145DC85-D209-4062-BC35-E24D27BC399E
com.adobe.lightroom
E38D2355-BD4D-45FE-9F1E-979F2493099A
com.apple.safari
EEE4C3FC-6104-4B32-A9C7-D708E30EB86C
com.apple.airplay
com.apple.bonjour
0343C308-CE79-4D3B-90F5-D32122234378
```

I want to bring the lowercase items to the top of the list, sort them alphabetically, and then drive the longer UUID strings to the bottom of the list.

```
com.adobe.lightroom
com.apple.airplay
com.apple.bonjour
com.apple.safari
00000000-0000-0000-A000-4A414D460003
0343C308-CE79-4D3B-90F5-D32122234378
C145DC85-D209-4062-BC35-E24D27BC399E
E38D2355-BD4D-45FE-9F1E-979F2493099A
EEE4C3FC-6104-4B32-A9C7-D708E30EB86C
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It is expected that you have attempted to solve the problem before posting a question - please edit you post to add any references, existing attempts, or relevant code.

Comment: did you try to use `cat <filename> | sort` or `sort <filename>`?

Comment: hi @azbarcea, i tried a sort initially and wound up with 00000 at the top and the com.* at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line == [a-z]* ]]; then
        printf "%s%c%s\n" "$line" $'\t' "A"
    else
        printf "%s%c%s\n" "$line" $'\t' "B"
    fi
done < list.txt | sort -t $'\t' -k2 -k1 | cut -f1
```

Result:

```
com.adobe.lightroom
com.apple.airplay
com.apple.bonjour
com.apple.safari
00000000-0000-0000-A000-4A414D460003
0343C308-CE79-4D3B-90F5-D32122234378
C145DC85-D209-4062-BC35-E24D27BC399E
E38D2355-BD4D-45FE-9F1E-979F2493099A
EEE4C3FC-6104-4B32-A9C7-D708E30EB86C
```

Its primitive approach is just to add a mark "A" or "B" in the second column to distinguish lowercase items from others.

As an alternative, if `perl` is your option, please try:

```
perl -e '
print map { $_->[0] }
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] or $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] }
    map { [$_, /^[a-z]/ ? 0 : 1] } <>;
' list.txt
```

It makes use of `Schwartzian transform` in Perl.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, great idea. You can add a letter using a simple regex with `sed`: `cat list.txt | sed 's/^[a-z]/A&/;t;s/^/B/;' | sort | cut -c2-`, this should be actually very fast.

Comment: Much better than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sort myfile.txt | tee >(grep -Pv "^[0-9A-F]{8}.+") >(grep -P "^[0-9A-F]{8}.+") > /dev/null
```

It first sorts the files, then greps for the UUID lines, and outputs them last.

My definition of a UUID is any line that starts with 8 characters from: `0-9` or `A-F` (capital).

Comment: @oguzismail using `|` stated as in your example would produce a different output (no output - to be more exact). Using `sort my.txt | tee >(grep -Pv "^[0-9A-F]{8}-.+")|(grep -P "^[0-9A-F]{8}.+")` it will filter only the UUID lines, dropping all others (e.g. `com.*`)

Answer (score 0):

A reverse "sort -r" will do this.   This works because if you look at the [ascii table](https://www.asciitable.com) you will notice the lower case alpha character are at the end.

```
$ cat output
00000000-0000-0000-A000-4A414D460003
C145DC85-D209-4062-BC35-E24D27BC399E
com.adobe.lightroom
E38D2355-BD4D-45FE-9F1E-979F2493099A
com.apple.safari
EEE4C3FC-6104-4B32-A9C7-D708E30EB86C
com.apple.airplay
com.apple.bonjour
0343C308-CE79-4D3B-90F5-D32122234378

$ sort -r output
com.apple.safari
com.apple.bonjour
com.apple.airplay
com.adobe.lightroom
EEE4C3FC-6104-4B32-A9C7-D708E30EB86C
E38D2355-BD4D-45FE-9F1E-979F2493099A
C145DC85-D209-4062-BC35-E24D27BC399E
0343C308-CE79-4D3B-90F5-D32122234378
00000000-0000-0000-A000-4A414D460003
```

However this doesn't sort the lowercase in alpha order. So switching to the lexical power of perl.

```
$ cat output | perl -e 'print sort {substr($b,0,1) cmp substr($a,0,1) || $a cmp $b} <>;'
com.adobe.lightroom
com.apple.airplay
com.apple.bonjour
com.apple.safari
E38D2355-BD4D-45FE-9F1E-979F2493099A
EEE4C3FC-6104-4B32-A9C7-D708E30EB86C
C145DC85-D209-4062-BC35-E24D27BC399E
00000000-0000-0000-A000-4A414D460003
0343C308-CE79-4D3B-90F5-D32122234378
```

Breaking down the perl command

- "-e" execute the following perl script
- print the results of sort where everything inside of {} is the custom sort compare
- "substr($b,0,1) cmp substr($a,0,1)" First reverse sort on the first character only.  It's a reverse sort because $b is first
- " || " or if they are the same value
- "$a comp $b" Does a normal sort on the line for values that have the same first character.
- <> reads from stdin

Comment: Hi @waltde, thanks. It's quite close but the sort -r does it alphabetically backwards.

Comment: @JimSmith my miss.  I updated the answer to account for this.